# need some help in configuring ingress with specific configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

just to understand: 6 micro services (frontend, backend, gateway, connectors, db's) builds up my application stack. Frontend is designed and developed in such a way, the application can be accessed on a TLS connection(need to config separately proper certs and domain name to enable TLS connection)

I have decided to use 5 namespaces and in each namespace i will deploy these 6 micro services. So that the application can be accessed in the below method.

example

`https://project-1.com will take me to https page of the frontend-1 in namespace "project-1" https://project-2.com will take me to https page of the frontend-2 in namespace "project-2" https://project-3.com will take me to https page of the frontend-3 in namespace "project-3" https://project-4.com will take me to https page of the frontend-4 in namespace "project-4" https://project-5.com will take me to https page of the frontend-5 in namespace "project-5"`

If i don't use an ingress, i may have to create and config certs for all frontends in each namespace which is a tedious work and involves cost to purchase each certs for each domain. (note: i have been asked not to use index based domain name certs)

SO I have decided to set up an ingress with a tls and that can route to frontend of the different namespaces using domain based routing.

example: create only one cert for the domain "production.application.com" and map the project using the domain name.

`https://production.application.com/project-1.com will take me to frontend-1 webpage in namespace "project-1"

https://production.application.com/project-2.com will take me to frontend-2 webpage in namespace "project-2"

https://production.application.com/project-3.com  will take me to frontend-3n webpage   in namespace "project-3"

https://production.application.com/project-4.com  will take me to  frontend-4  webpage  in namespace "project-4"

https://production.application.com/project-5.com  will take me to frontend-5 webpage  in namespace "project-5" `

and all this should have a tls connection.

Any suggestion or ideas or alternatives are welcomed. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have taken is fine and should be like that way.

Ingress has the single **TLS** **cert** stored in **secret** and attached to it and you are doing the **Path-based routing**.

To automate the process of cert-creation, and renewal you can use the [cert-manger](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) for the same.

Comment: implementing tls certs for ingress and tls certs at  front-end microservice. Isn't this contradictory?

Comment: for you can use the cert-manager which will manage the cert and re-new it as per requirement. https://cert-manager.io/docs/